# flutter: IOS - how can I make Audioplayers duck external music, instead of stop it?

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, avaudiosession

I know that iOS assigns only **one** audio session to all plugins in the same app. So in my app, I record and play voice-messages. It is possible that a user might be playing music on another app while using my app; so my app needs to **duck** the external music while I play or record a voicenote (i.e my app should not stop external music, but **duck** it, and then **continue** it when the voice message is finished).

I've tried to use the "audio_session" plugin to set up an iOS audio session to duck external music; and activate that audio session right before playing the voice-message using "AudioPlayers"; but it seems that when the voice-message starts playing, the plugin overrides the audio_session settings and stops external music.

Heres some code:

I use audio_session plugin to configure the session like so:

```
Future configurePlayOnlySession() async {
    sessionPO = await AudioSession.instance;
    myOptions = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers;
    myNotify = AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation;

await sessionPO.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
  avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playback,
  avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: myOptions,
  avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.spokenAudio,
  avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy:
      AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
  avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: myNotify,
  androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
    contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.speech,
    flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
    usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication,
  ),
  androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransientMayDuck,
  androidWillPauseWhenDucked: false,
));

print("Audio configuration complete");
}
```

then I activate the session before playing the audio like so:

```
    if (await sessionPO.setActive(true)) { //If I pause here then external music ducks
  await audioCache.play( //But once I call this, external music is stopped
    'beep.wav',
  );
}
```

After calling setActive on sessionPO, external music ducks perfectly. But then when I play the sound, external music stops. It's like the Audioplayer overrides the sessionPO configuration.

Comment: By saying "duck the song" you mean that the external music must play at a lower volume? or you mean the external song must be paused and played after the voice messaage?

Comment: I mean play at a lower volume

Comment: But wether the external song pauses or ducks(plays at lower volume),  the important thing is it must continue playing after the user finished the voice message on my app. Currently it just stops completely.

Comment: Anything you have already tried?

Comment: I switched audio plugins to see if the problem was plugin-specific. I tried assets_audio_player and Audioplayers; both didn't won't. I tried multiple combinations of AudioSessionCategories and AudioSessionCategoryOptions and AudeioSessionModes using audio_session. I switched between internet sound source, local sound source, asset sound source. I tried to load the sound first without playing, then activate the session, then play the sound. All did not work.

Comment: Any assistance on this? It would really be appreciated. I still haven't found the solution

Comment: Didn't find any good solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound/versions/4.0.0-beta.2) documentation here, I came across this which I think might solve your problem:

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
    await flutterSoundPlayer.iosSetCategory( t_IOS_SESSION_CATEGORY.PLAY_AND_RECORD, t_IOS_SESSION_MODE.DEFAULT, IOS_DUCK_OTHERS |  IOS_DEFAULT_TO_SPEAKER );
```

See the link I shared for more details